# suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ real matrix and $A^\top A$ is $3\times3$ nonsingular matrix, then $n =$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices, transpose

the answer of this question is $n<3$ , why? I mean how we decided that is $n<3$ when $A$ multiply $A^\top$ will be singular?

Comment: sorry the answer is n>3 but i still didn't get it

Comment: $A$ is $m\times n$, so $A^\top$ is $n\times m$. What do you get when you multiply $m\times n$ matrix by $n\times m$ matrix? What else is special about the product? If you're not familiar with the particular matrix product $A^\top A$, try it out with simple examples of $A$ for small $m,n$.

Comment: *"the answer of this question is $n<3$"*, this is incorrect. Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and $\det(B)\neq 0$ (i.e. not singular), $\text{rank}(B)=3$. That being said, you need to check matrices' sizes and confirm this fact.

Answer (score 1):

How the resulting matrix of $A^T A$ corresponds to $m \times n$ should be quite visible when familiarizing yourself with the matrix products as stated in the comments.

As to why $n \geq 3$, we have to look at the rank of the matrix. If $n < 3$, the rank of the matrix would be less than $3$ as well (since rank is equal to column rank).

Now furthermore the rank of $A^T$ equals the rank of $A$ (again rank equals column rank equals row rank).

And at last if the rank of $A$ was less than $3$, the rank of $A^T A$ (the composition of $A^T$ and $A$) would have to be less than or equal to the minimum of the ranks of the two matrices. Which would be less than 3 and $A^T A$ would not be invertible/non-singular.

As such we get that $n \geq 3$.

Comment: A comment would be more appropriate here. Also, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all math expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint I seem to have forgotten it at one point. As far as I know comments are limited to 600 characters so it would not have been possible to post it as such. Furthermore it answers the question